# Fail to import a Module: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging

Am try to get my head around python package and module, 
in a structure below in serengeti.py  i import arusha module by doing `from ubongo.arusha import Lake`(lake is a method in arusha module) i get an error "ModuleNotFoundError" do i need to add to PYTHONPATH. i dont know what am doing wrong any help you can provide on my learning journey i would appreciate

```
ubongo
      |
       __init__.py
      |
       arusha.py
      |
      manyara 
             |
             __init__.py
             |
              serengeti.py
```

Answer (score 0):

you need the ubongo parent to be the working directory or to be on PYTHOPATH.

The former option is the better practice as messing with PYTHONPATH can make problems.

Comment: This means every simple package i made must be on PYTHONPATH

Comment: no. like i said you need to run your program from your project folder which is the parent of your top package. The parent of ubongo in your case.